# Angular hide and showing multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

Farely new to angular, and I've tried looking online for examples of what I'm trying to achieve, but all of the examples don't seem to be helping me

I have 5 tabs, each tab represents a body of info. I want it to originally show the first boxes info, but when you click on the other boxes, it will replace it with the other boxes info

So basically, a hide and show. Only showing the info of the box I clicked. Heres a layout of what I mean
HTML:

```
<div class="boxes">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="box1-content">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box2-content">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box3-content">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box4-content">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box5-content">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .boxes {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    .box {
     height: 100px;
     background: red;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZZYpR

Comment: Use `*ngIf`. You should read the Angular documentation at length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your `.html` like this

```
<div class="boxes">
<div class="box" (click)="tabToggle(1)">box1</div>
<div class="box" (click)="tabToggle(2)">box2</div>
<div class="box" (click)="tabToggle(3)">box3</div>
<div class="box" (click)="tabToggle(4)">box4</div>
<div class="box" (click)="tabToggle(5)">box5</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showTab == 1" class="box1-content">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div *ngIf="showTab == 2" class="box2-content">Lorem ipsum 2</div>
<div *ngIf="showTab == 3" class="box3-content">Lorem ipsum 3</div>
<div *ngIf="showTab == 4" class="box4-content">Lorem ipsum 4</div>
<div *ngIf="showTab == 5" class="box5-content">Lorem ipsum 5</div>
```

add this line on your `.ts` file's under component.

```
  showTab = 1;
  tabToggle(index){
    this.showTab =index;
  }
```

Comment: Hey do you happen to have a working codepen link? I tried your code but it doesn't seem to be working

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZZYpR

Comment: Please check stackblitz url [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8reazh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

hope I can help some!

First I would set the content boxes to `display: none;` (using css) and then attach a `click` function to your .box divs which might look like this:

```
<div class="boxes">
<div class="box" (click)="showThis = 'show1'"></div>
<div class="box" (click)="showThis = 'show2'"></div>
<div class="box" (click)="showThis = 'show3'"></div>
<div class="box" (click)="showThis = 'show4'"></div>
<div class="box" (click)="showThis = 'show5'"></div>
</div>

<div class="box1-content" *ngIf="showThis == 'show1'">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box2-content" *ngIf="showThis == 'show2'">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box3-content" *ngIf="showThis == 'show3'">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box4-content" *ngIf="showThis == 'show4'">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="box5-content" *ngIf="showThis == 'show5'">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
```

Also, my first choice would be to use a library like Material or even bootstrap so you don't have to worry about all this logic/styling. But either way, hope this helps!